# Memory error when for-loop contains too many videos (python, psychopy function visual.MovieStim3)

Tags: python, memory, video, psychopy

I created a loop that shows a video in each iteration. For a few iterations, it seems to work fine. However, when I include all videos (106), I run into memory error problems each time.

The code is Python. The video object is created with the Psychopy function 'visual.MovieStim3'. I am not entirely sure about the video objects being the issue here. But because I thought they were, I tried to delete the video objects after their presentation using the following snippets, but it did not work:

> ```
> del video._mov
> video._unload()
> win.clearBuffer()
> ```

This is the video snippet from within the loop:

> ```
> # play the video
> video = visual.MovieStim3(win, filename = trialArray[trial], 
>     size=(1920,1200), flipVert=False, flipHoriz=False, loop=False,
>     opacity=(1.0))
> current_time = trial_clock.getTime()
> while trial_clock.getTime() < current_time + 6.6:
>     video.draw()
>     win.flip()
>     # start registering potential keypresses
>     keypress_video = event.getKeys(keyList=None, modifiers=False, timeStamped=trial_clock)
>     if keypress_video != []:
>         keypresses.append(keypress_video)
>         # include the escape key as a way to exit the experiment. 
>         if keypress_video[0][0] == 'escape':
>             print ('Sie haben das Experiment verlassen.')
>             sys.exit()
>         else:
>             pass
>     else:
>         pass
> video_duration = trial_clock.getTime() - current_time
> video.stop()
> ```

The current error message I get is this: 
"Memory Error
portaudio error in Pa_AbortStream: Wait timed out"

Before, I was trying different things by trial and error : 
- changed the default opening program from pythonw.exe to python.exe 
--> this changed the crashing behaviour to black screen plus error message in python shell:
'Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault'

- I deleted the pygame folders in the site-package-folder of my python library
  --> this does not help (much). after 51 videos/trials, the code crashes
- I try what happens if I run the script from within psychopy again, to get an error message.
  --> after some time, loading of video takes terribly long (long presentation of each first fix-cross), plus I get error message:
  MemoryError
  portaudio error in Pa_AbortStream: Wait timed out

-> implemented the code to clear buffer
--> get error message after memory fills up:
"Memory Error
portaudio error in Pa_AbortStream: Wait timed out"

Answer (score 0):

so for those interested in the same problem: I also posted the question in the psychopy forum where we solved it:

https://discourse.psychopy.org/t/memory-error-when-for-loop-contains-too-many-videos-python-psychopy-function-visual-moviestim3/8610

Best wishes,
Juliane